# Dd_belatedPng issue with content loaded on callback with jquery.fade()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, iepngfix, dd-belatedpng

I'm loading some some html into a div through ajax using jquery. Once the content is loaded, I need to fix pngs for ie6, using DD_belatedPNG. Code below -

```
$("#content").fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).html("<div><p>some text</p><img src='myimage.png' class='dayPosted' /><p>some more text</p></div>").fadeIn( fixIeIssue() ); //The html in this function is for example only, in my app it's populated by ajax. 
})
fixIeIssue = function(){
    if  (window.DD_belatedPNG){
        //alert("for some reason this works if I call an alert here")
        DD_belatedPNG.fix('.dayPosted');
    }
}
```

The png fix is not working. Oddly, it does work if I call an alert before calling the fix.

I've tried adding a document.ready into the fixIeIssue but that didn't help.

The png fix does work on the initial page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass function as argument. You also forget about 1st argument of [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). Try:

```
$("#content").fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).html("<div><p>some text</p><img src='myimage.png' class='dayPosted' /><p>some more text</p></div>").fadeIn('slow', fixIeIssue );
})
```

Your version would work if `fixIeIssue()` will return a function, but it doesn't.

Comment: Ooops, didn't realise it was as simple as that. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly certain the the first argument is optional -  .fadeIn( fixIeIssue ) work's just fine.

Comment: Right so, I'll leave it in then. Don't want any random errors appearing later. Thanks.